# How can i filter specific sms messages with its specific content (like rude words)

Tags: android

I have been working on a project.but i faced a problem. when i launch my app it stopps. this app is for filtering incoming sms by searching for a string array in them. i have coded it but it crashes.
i have used this code

```
SMSReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        if(bundle!=null){
            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus"); 
            for(int i=0;i<pdusObj.length;i++){
                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                String smsSender = phoneNumber;
                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                String smsText = message; 
                String[] comparing =getResources().getStringArray(R.array.compare);

                try {
                    Scanner txtscan = new Scanner(new File(smsText));

                    while(txtscan.hasNextLine()){
                        for(int f = 0;f<=comparing.length;f++){
                            String str = txtscan.nextLine();
                            if(str.indexOf(comparing[f]) != -1){
                                abortBroadcast();
                            }
                            else break;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                    break;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use:

```
message = message.replaceAll(String stringToRemove, String replacement)
```

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: thank u dude for your help.but what I meant by filtering is actually finding a special word from massage string and stop the massage from being received by abortbroadcast().

Comment: Okay sorry, I can't help with this one then.